# RESTful URI design

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm looking for a right way to represent searches as a RESTful uri.

I have two models: countries and states, where countries have a collection the states.

What's the right way to represent a search for countries with id or name attributes?

```
api/countries/1/id

api/countries/Italy/name
```

or

```
api/countries?id=1

api/countries?name=Italy
```

Also, if I want view the list of states?

```
api/countries/1/id/states

api/countries/Italy/name/states
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these two models ie.  `countries` and `states`, I think following Uri patterns will be most appropriate.

1. All Countries :    `api/country`
2. Specific Country : `api/country/{England}`
3. All States : `api/country/{England}/State`
4. Specific State : `api/country/{England}/State/{Berkshire}`

in above example value  inside `{}` represents the variables.

Comment: @user2007820 hi, this is what i thought. Now please respond to it, if you have any query.

Comment: Hi, ok perfect...but, I need to search both by id and by name. How can i distinguish this to requests?

Comment: @user2007820 ok for this you can do that, just add `Id` suffix to api like `api/countryId/{12}`, `api/countryId/12/{stateId}`. OR you can also do that without changing the url. For this you need to search parameter value in namefiled as well Id field in your database. hopefully you got it. please respond :)

Comment: So, in your opinion, the correct way would be:
`/api/countryid/{12}/states` => all states of country with id 12
`/api/countryname/{Italy}/states` => all states of country with name Italy
Thanks

Comment: Yes this would be more self explanatory uri for your Rest Api's. Users can easily understand what this url going to be returned. So just go ahed and yes please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your tastes. Both variant are ok.

For states it's possible to create new endpoint

```
api/states/name/Italy
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach, using name in the REST URL is wrong. The name is simply an attribute of the country not a sub-resource, meaning you should not see it in the URL. An option would be though, to use it as key and in this case, the name's **value** could be used in place of the ID.

```
api/countries/Italy
```

I think what you are trying to achieve though, is to filter fields, i.e. get only the names:

```
api/countries/Italy/states?fields=name
```

or, if you predefine some formats

```
api/countries/Italy/states?format=onlyName
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the right way to represent a search for countries with id or name attributes?

tl;dr: **Variant one is a recipe for confusion**. If having to choose, use the *query string* to *search*.

---

As far as the REST manifesto is concerned the URI logic is merely an implementation detail  - the only concern is that the access mechanism at that location mustn't break over time. Content may be emptied or move - but URI must at all times end up at a service endpoint that gives clients a pre-response they understand and can act on (i.e. 3** redirect or hypermedia re-discovery by the client).

However, many successful and well-designed APIs try to expose an inherently consistent logic, aiming to become intuitively explorable. Therefore your first example  `api/countries/1/id`  is actually **BAD** regarding developer's experience and market success, as it be confusing to use:

1. From looking at the URI, you don't have any clue that you're running a (potentially CPU/Memory-expensive) search and NOT retrieving a single ressource
2. Many public APIs follow a logical mapping between resource hierarchy and the exposed URIs  - so a common expectation would be that `api/countries/1/id` retrieves `{1}` (being a pointless query) or that `api/countries/1/name` gives `{Italy}`.

Therefore, *Query* string is an excellent option -  especially to offer a *Search* functionality. One can see the implication from the words ;)

```
api/countries?name=Italy 
api/countries?q=name(Ital*)              // same result
api/countries?q=isoCode=(IT)             // same result

--> api/countries/1/states               // list all states of Italy
    api/states?q=country/name(Italy)     // - same -
    api/states?q=country/id(1)           // - same -
```

The response body of a request can be anticipated from looking at the URI only, which is nice. Better yet: it helps to tell apart resource and view. The "view" is defined in the query string, think of as lens, or filter, through which you look at extracts of what otherwise is one and the same resource (your countries collection).

This pattern is just as good in those regards and also commonly found:

```
api/countries/search/Italy
api/countries/search/name=Italy
api/countries/search/isoCode=IT,name=*aly
```

The reason to pick this may revolve around actual implementation details when building your API - as it seperates the direct access to a resource from a search operation - both the required CPU/Memory to fulfill the request, and the response count and format may be fundamentally different.